# How to re-render a React component using new props after submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the user select options, these are saved in the state of the parent component. The parent component is the entire web page with the "form".

When the user presses "Submit", I want the child component that uses these options to re-render using these new props passed into it. A default generation is visible when you load the page.

However, I don't want it done before 'Submit' is pressed, only after.

All I can think of is to remove the element from the node and regenerate it but this is not a good way to use React. Let me know if more clarification/context is needed. I am new to React and I am doing this project to familiarize myself with it and it's behaviors.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is the re-rendering of the child component when the props passed to it(the child component) change. A component re-renders when its state changes, so you can let the child component have its own state, and the state value are initialized(or componentDidMount) by the props. So anytime the props change, state would automatically change and hence the component will re-render after you press the Submit button.

Also if you want the child component to be rendered only after the Submit button has been pressed, you can maintain **isVisible** in the state and conditionally render it using ternary operator or if__else block

Comment: The parent component is the entire web page with the "form". The child component is something that generates depending on the inputs of that form, however a default generation is visible when you load the page.

How would I change the props when the child element already been constructed?

Comment: You can set the initial state with as the default values you want, and in the componentDidMount you can have this.setState({ // the state changes come here }) and inside it you can set the state with the props of the form. So initially it would be rendered by the default state, and when you submit, the component re-renders and the props initialize the state and appears on the ui.